# How can I change the default commands on a float environment?

Tags: floats, captions, abnt, abntex2

I am making a template for my academic work for uni (with pdfLaTeX on Overleaf) and I wanted to set a different set of commands to `\begin{figure}` and `\begin{table}` environments automatically. I need it to show the format and commands that I want automatically everytime I type '\begin{figure}' or '\begin{table}', such as the caption on top for the image and a caption* after, and the letters at 10pt size. For example:

The default would be:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics{}
   \caption{Caption}
   \label{fig:lable}
\end{figure}
```

which is what Overleaf automatically fills when you use the '\begin{figure}' command. And, as to fit the university's standards, I need it to be:

```
 \begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \fontsize{10pt}{15pt}\selectfont
    \caption{\MakeUppercase{legenda}}
    \includegraphics[]{}
    \caption*{Fonte: }
    \label{fig:label} % colocar um apelido e usar \autoref{--apelido--} para se referenciar a esta imagem
\end{figure}
```

And to change the `\begin{table}` to something like:

```
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \fontsize{10pt}{15pt}\selectfont
  \caption{\MakeUppercase{legenda}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccc}
        \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} & \textbf{Col 3} \\ \hline \hline
          &  &   \\
          &  &   \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \caption*{Fonte: }
  \label{tab:tabela} % colocar um apelido e usar \autoref{--apelido--} para se referenciar a esta tabela
\end{table}
```

I want the codes I showed to be automatic when you call the environments, since writing them down everytime would be tiring and the user would definatelly forget to change some images. So it needs to be a command that works for everyone that uses the template and that doesn't allow the user to forget anything (by substituting the defaults with the commands I wrote). It would also be ideal (but not necessary) that it worked on other platforms/LaTeX editors as well.
How can I do that? How can I change the default autofill of a float environment to all users? I'd like to not need to create a new type of environment.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and *Saudações do Brasil*. 1, read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)s, it is always better to get help from people here. 2, I'd suggest using [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [subcaption](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages, it'll format your whole file better, faster and simpler. You don't need a `caption*` to add the source (*Fonte*) of your data, you can just insert it. Using commands `captionbox` and `subcaptionbox` are the way to go.

Comment: your question is not very clear as what you are showing is the source so you write the environment. if you mean you want some editor shortcut or menu option to add that figure template that may be possible but you would need to say what editor you are using